# Git clone or submodule update does not find private key file if depth flag is set

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, private-key, shallow-clone

I'm cloning a repository with a few submodules. In order to save time I'm doing a shallow clone passing the private key as environment variable. Example:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i temp_pvt_key.key" git clone -b my_branch --depth=1 git@my-repo.com:my_team/my_repo.git temp_repo
```

The command above works just fine! But when I try do the same with submodules adding the `--depth=1`, git is not able to find the `temp_pvt_key.key` anymore.

**Error:**

```
Cloning into 'C:/path/to/submodule/folder'...
Warning: Identity file ../temp_pvt_key.key not accessible: No such file or directory.
git@my-repo.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

*I'm using relative path (`../`) once the private key file is in the repository parent folder.*

**Works but the whole submodule repository is cloned:**

```
cd temp_repo
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ../temp_pvt_key.key" git submodule update --init
```

**Basically the same command plus --depth=1. This does not work at all:**

```
cd temp_repo
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ../temp_pvt_key.key" git submodule update --depth=1 --init
```

**I've tried in a single command too but no success, I ended up with the same error:**

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i temp_pvt_key.key" git clone -b my_branch --depth=1 --recursive --shallow-submodules git@my-repo.com:my_team/my_repo.git temp_repo
```

Could I workaround this problem somehow?

*Git version: `git version 2.19.2.windows.1`*

Answer (score 0):

First, [upgrade to Git For Windows 2.25.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (many submodule bug/fixes/evolution might have occurred since 2.19)

Second, the syntax for [a `--depth` parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) is `--depth 1`, not `--depth=1`